# Could not find a command named "devtools"

Tags: dart

[Docs](https://dart.dev/tools/dart-devtools#2-launch-the-devtools-server) says

> If the system cache bin directory is in your path, then you can just run dart devtools, without dart pub global run.

But if I run

```
dart devtools
```

I get this error:

> Could not find a command named "devtools".

However, I can do

```
devtools
```

and

```
dart pub global run devtools
```

But why can't I run `dart devtools` as mentioned in the docs?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this is false: "If the system cache bin directory is in your path".  So if you really want that to work, fix that.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry I didn't get what to fix, should I remove the directory from the `PATH`?